# How to add a play/pause button in revolution slider in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, button, revolution-slider

I have a revolution slider with a video from vimeo, that video autoplays when the web page is loaded, but due the Google Chrome autoplay policy changes, in google chrome does not autoplay it only works when I click on the video, but I want a button, so how can I add a play button in my revolution slider?

I have tried what in this page is explained, but it doesn't work for me.
https://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/layer-actions-links/#play-pause-slider
https://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/layer-actions-links/#play-pause-video

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a button from "`Add Layer`".

[image]

Now go to `Actions` and add `Click` event as "`Start Media`".

[image]

And I hope you added video like this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. All you did is what I have already done, I don't see what I'm doing wrong, but it doesn't work. I'll keep looking for a solution, thanks!

Comment: @S.Marx will be easier if you can show what have u done. So we can figure out the problem/issue with your settings.

Comment: I've added some pictures, of what I have done , without the buttons. I tried what you told me yesterday, but it still not working.

Comment: @S.Marx I can't find the button to play the video ... Please add that along with the click event as i provided.. and do let me know if that doesn't work...

Comment: If you are looking for the button in the web page you will not find it, thats a revolution slider that I created to do tests. I have a added an image where I show how I've added the button and the event, exactly like you told me.

Comment: is it hosted anywhere where I can check the issue? Coz I used the same steps and mine is working but not yours..

Comment: OOOH, I've realised that the play button does not work on the first click. Then I click on the revolution slider to play the video, it starts, then I click again, it pauses the video, and now I click on the button and works. I don't know why I doesn't work on the first click.

Comment: Must be issue with the version you are using...can you try to change cover and see if its working correctly..

Comment: I agree with you, the version is not working, I have done what you told me and all the tutorials I follow don't work. I've already tried changing the cover and also trying it with another video. I really appreciate the time you took to help me! Thank you very much Himanshu Bansal!

Comment: I am using version 5.2.4.1 .....Try updating the version...or rolling back down.. could be a bug in newer version... If its ok.. accept the answer.. other users who might come looking for the same issue find it useful.